# HTTP Error 401.3 for specific .pdf file

Tags: http, pdf, asp-classic, http-status-code-401

I just uploaded two .pdf files on my server. They are both in the same folder.

The first one can be normally accessed but for the second one I get an 
**HTTP Error 401.3 "You are not authorized to view this page"**

This looks weird to me. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: is it really 401.3 or is it 401 or 403?

Answer (score 1):

check filesystem permission if you are running linux. the user running the webserver should have read permission on both files you can do this with most ftp software or if you have shell access `chmod a+r /path/to/your/file.pdf`

if that does not solve the problem look for error in log file usually /var/log/apache/error.log

Comment: hello and thank you for your reply. My server uses IIS - windows server 2003 and I do not have ftp access. I manage files using remote access. I checked the file's permissions. There are permissions setted for "adrministrator", "administrators" and "system". Should I add more groups?